# How to remove <?xml at *start of line* with sed?

Tags: sed

I have a file whose first line starts with `<?xml`

I can remove it with sed using

```
/<\?xml/d
```

but if I try and ensure start of line -

```
/^<\?xml/d
```

it doesn't match.
However other lines such as

```
<head ...
```

are removed with

```
/^<head/d
```

I also tried

```
/^\<\?xml/d
```

but no match.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use:

```
sed '/^<?xml/d' filename
```

Under GNU sed, `\?` means zero or one of the preceding character.  (In POSIX sed, `\?` is undefined.)  Since you want to match a literal `?`, leave it unescaped.

#### Examples

Let's consider this test file:

```
$ cat filename
<?xml deleteme
<.xml keepme
..xml keepme
```

The solution above produces the desired result:

```
$ sed '/^<?xml/d' filename
<.xml keepme
..xml keepme
```

The first command in the question incorrectly produces no results:

```
$ sed '/<\?xml/d' filename
$
```

This is because it matches all lines which contain `xml` optionally preceded by `<`.  Since all lines contain `xml`, they are all deleted.

The second command deletes nothing:

```
$ sed '/^<\?xml/d' filename
<?xml deleteme
<.xml keepme
..xml keepme
```

This deletes any line that starts with zero or one `<` followed *immediately* by `xml`.  Since the lines always have at least one character between `<` and `xml`, no lines are deleted.

#### How to escape characters when in doubt

If you are unsure if a character is regex active and you want to deactivate it, the safe thing to do is put it in square brackets:

```
$ sed '/^[<][?]xml/d' filename
<.xml keepme
..xml keepme
```

Inside `[...]`, all characters are treated as literal characters.

Answer (score 5):

In POSIX [Basic Regular Expression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03), the behavior of `\?` is undefined (some other escaped sequences for GNU sed are `\|`, `\+` and more [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Escapes)).

GNU sed used BRE by default and it treats those escape sequence as special characters, meaning `\?` is the same as `?`, matching zero or one character.

So `<\?xml` mean zero or one `<` follow by `xml`, which matched `<?xml`. [With BRE, only `^`, `$`, `*`, `.`, `\` and `[` are special characters](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_03), so just leave all other characters untouched if you want to match literal

```
sed -e '/^<?xml/d' <file
```

If you want to stick with escaped sequence to match literal string, just enable [Extended Regular Expression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) (which will [become POSIX standard in next version](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=528)):

```
sed -E '/^\?xml/d' <file
```

(`sed -E` work with BSD sed)

Answer (score 2):

> I have a file whose first line starts with `<?xml`
>   [...] if I try and ensure start of line `/^<\?xml/d` it doesn't match

It is possible that the text is preceded by a [Byte Order Mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). These are common in UTF-16 format files (particularly those from Windows systems) and are used to indicate the *endianness* of the bytes comprising the 16-bit characters in the file.

You can check this with one of the many hex dump tools (`hex`, `hexdump`, `od -c` for three) and looking at the first few characters. If you see `FF FE` or `FE FF` as the first two characters it's a BOM.

Since it's probably better to keep the BOM in place you will best achieve the solution simply by removing the start-of-line requirement from your RE.

Incidentally, if you're trying to extract data from an XML file you would generally be better off parsing it properly rather than digging through it with REs. (There are exceptions, of course, but I'm speaking about the general case, which allows for unexpected but valid reformatting of the file, comment structures, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

If this is a result of xml transformation (`xsltprox foo.xsl bar.xml` for instance), the xml line is on first line only.

Use either:

```
awk 'NR>1'
```

When in pipe, or:

```
awk 'FNR>1' file1 file2 ... > result
```

with multiple files.

```
 sed -i -e 1d file1 file2 ...
```